# from countif (dynamic range) in excel to python (pandas)

Tags: python

I'm a newbie on python.
I wanna reply this on python (column B):

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbgc3.png)

I try with this:

```
countif_clmn =df.iloc[0:df.index,1].sum()

df["count"] =countif_clmn
```

but it doesn't work.

The error is:

```
TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers [RangeIndex(start=0, stop=20, step=1)] of type RangeIndex
```

How can I do it?
Thanks in advance, imack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to reproduce excel *countif* function. The idea is very similar to your initial approach where we filter for each unique day. Then, get the index from the filtered data frame (always assured that increment of 1 after dropping the original indices). Then, we assign the that index while adding 1 since Python indices start with 0 unlike the desired output from an Excel *countif* function.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'day': ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Tuesday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Friday', 'Wednesday', 'Tuesday', 'Tuesday',
                           'Sunday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Wednesday', 'Wednesday', 'Monday', 'Friday', 'Monday']})
df['count'] = 0
for unique_day in df.day.unique():
  df.loc[df['day'] == unique_day, 'count'] = (df[df['day'] == unique_day].reset_index(drop = True).index + 1).to_list()
```

> Output

```
          day  count
0      Sunday      1
1      Monday      1
2      Friday      1
3    Saturday      1
4     Tuesday      1
5     Tuesday      2
6   Wednesday      1
7      Friday      2
8   Wednesday      2
9     Tuesday      3
10    Tuesday      4
11     Sunday      2
12     Friday      3
13   Saturday      2
14  Wednesday      3
15  Wednesday      4
16     Monday      2
17     Friday      4
18     Monday      3
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Is this the fastest method or are there others?